# How to create new WPF Application in the same AppDomain after shutdown the old one

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ironpython, appdomain

I'm using IronPython as a scripting extension which was hosted in another application.  I will be in the same AppDomain forever unless I restart the parent application which is very costly to do (takes about 1 minutes to restart).

Right now I'm building a WPF dialog and it works fine the first time, but the second time it'll fail because it tries to create another `Application` in the same AppDomain.  Is there a way to create a new `Application` in the same AppDomain after the old `Application` was shutdown?

It is directly related to this post, but from a different angle (posted by me as well): [How to close WPF window without shutdown .NET Application in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239880/how-to-close-wpf-window-without-shutdown-net-application-in-ironpython)

Comment: And why do you need to shutdown the original Application?

Comment: Because it was automatically shutdown when I close the WPF dialog window.  I've tried set `app.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown` then the whole application froze.  Do I need handle the WPF window close event by making such setting?

Comment: You can mimic the situation I have by running the code snippet in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239880/how-to-close-wpf-window-without-shutdown-net-application-in-ironpython INSIDE IronPython REPL.  I believe you are in the same AppDomain unless you close and restart a new IronPython REPL.

Comment: I believe the answer to this question is that it is impossible to create a new Application, and you need to reuse a single Application for this. See the answer here: [How to close WPF window without shutdown .NET Application in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239880/how-to-close-wpf-window-without-shutdown-net-application-in-ironpython/60242302#60242302)

Comment: In case other people ran into the same issue, the solution to avoid this situation is by not invoking `Application` at all, but simply use `ShowDialog`.  See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239880/how-to-close-wpf-window-without-shutdown-net-application-in-ironpython